# How can I determine if the current version of Windows is either 32-bit or 64-bit from the command line?

Tags: windows, computer-architecture, cpu-architecture, windows-edition

What's the command line to find out if the OS is running a 32-bit version or 64-bit of Windows?

Comment: In what language?!

Comment: @AlixAxel, well they said *command-line*, so presumably, if anything, Batch.

Answer (score 39):

You can get this via WMI:

```
wmic OS get OSArchitecture
```

Example on my system:

```
C:\>wmic OS get OSArchitecture
OSArchitecture
32-bit
```

Comment: I like this answer (gotta go learn me some WMI console :) ), but I gotta give it to "systeminfo" for keystrokes. ;)

Comment: XP?​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 20):

Command line:

```
systeminfo | findstr /I type:
```

example output:

```
System type:               X86-based PC
```

X86 indicates a 32-bit system in this example.

(`/I` *parameter indicates case-insensitive search*)

Comment: I gave you a point for keystrokes, and then you made it longer. hehe :)

Comment: It's not my answer :P

Comment: But is "X86-based PC" the same as OSArchitecture 32-bit? You can run 32-bit Win XP on an x64 processor.

Comment: be careful if your OS language is german(or maybe any other than englisch)! I have to change to `systeminfo | findstr /I typ:` as the whole entry is `Systemtyp: x64-based PC`

Comment: `systeminfo | findstr /C:"System Type"` also retrieves the same information, but I guess longer text so less preferred.

Answer (score 16):

I can not attach answer to another post so here.
Piping the result of `systeminfo` - is taking a quite good amount in time and writes to the console so is not the best solution for command files (batch scripts - anyhow You like to call them B-) ).

Even with the `findstr` - it does not find this on other language version of windows.
On a central european language win7 os it also returns ..."X86-based"... on the result but something other on then the "type" were looking for. I am not sure that it can vary on other language variants of the os.

Probably the "wmic" method is the most reliable - it asks the os directly.

Other possible quick solution can be to examine a variable (at least working on win7 at me).

```
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
```

Ok - it is quite long to remember but possible a `set | findstr ARCH` can be remembered.

Sure - some can modify a system variable so not that reliable than `wmic`. But can be used quickly.

I hope I could help someone out.

Comment: I wasn't sure the echo command would work on my XP box because I've never seen this environment variable before (perhaps because I've never looked for it), but it does. +1 for a simple solution.

Comment: +1 because it specifies ARM/AMD architecture as well.

Answer (score 15):

There are numerous ways to check the processor architecture under Windows:

- The fastest, easiest, and most compatible way to check the processor architecture in [at least Windows 2000](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc959490%28v=technet.10%29) and up is to examine the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` [environment variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details#environment_variables):

  `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`
- However, this can give different results, depending on the way in which the command-prompt is opened. To avoid getting [“unexpected results” due to WoW64](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201140747/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/howto-detect-process-bitness.aspx), you can read it directly from the registry (Microsoft made no less than [two typos in the key](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215061908/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/556009)):

  `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`
- Microsoft also suggests reading the hardware information store from the registry:

  `reg query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" /v Identifier`
- You can also check for the existence of the x86 version of the `Program Files` directory (or the [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) that points to it) since it would only exist on a 64-bit system. Unlike the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` variable, this is not dependant on the way that the command prompt is run since the directory exists (or not) regardless of how the prompt is opened:

  - `::via env-var`
    `if not defined ProgramFiles(x86) echo 32-bit`
  - `::via file-system`
    `if not exist "%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)" echo 32-bit`

These methods can be combined in a single batch-file (e.g., `cpuinfo.bat`) and provides a nice, lightning fast way to check the system from a standard Windows NT command-prompt without needing to resort to running other programs or frameworks.

The batch-file below was tested on 32-bit and Intel 64-bit systems (please test on AMD64), giving correct results in <1 second:

[image: Test results]

```
@echo off

echo PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE var:
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% | find /i "x86" > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.

echo PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE reg:
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE | find /i "x86" > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.

echo CentralProcessor reg:
reg query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.

echo ProgramFiles(x86) var:
if not defined ProgramFiles(x86) (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.

echo ProgramFiles(x86) dir:
if not exist "%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)" (
    echo   32-bit
) else (
    echo   64-bit
)
echo.
```

Answer (score 7):

I could not find the `OSArchitecture` property (as per phoebus' answer) so I would suggest using the `SystemType` property in `ComputerSystem` instead.

Running the command `wmic computersystem get systemtype` from a command prompt gives

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic computersystem get systemtype  

SystemType x64-based PC
```

Answer (score 4):

Regular command line: `wmic OS get OSArchitecture`  (IIRC)

PowerShell: `(gwmi win32_computersystem).SystemType`

Comment: I get `Invalid Query` in XP.

Answer (score 1):

if you are referring to windows OS, you can use vbscript with WMI

```
strComputer = "."    
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=Pkt}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")    
Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")

For Each objProcessor In colSettings
Wscript.Echo "System Type: " & objProcessor.Architecture
Wscript.Echo "Processor: " & objProcessor.Description
Wscript.Echo "Address Width: "& objProcessor.AddressWidth
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find that Information using "System Information"

> Start-> Run -> winmsd.exe

Under "System Summary"/ System Type you can find the OS version

> X64 -> 64 Bit
>   X86 -> 32 Bit

JohnT's answer in GUI ;)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Start » Run and then type `cmd`. Now you will be in command prompt. There you can type  `systeminfo` and then press enter. It takes a few seconds to get all your system information. You can find the processor data too.

```
 Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel
```

- x86 Family means, your processor is 32-bit.
- x64 Family means, your processor is 64-bit.

> C:\Documents and Settings\mr85464>systeminfo

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows XP Professional
OS Version:                5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Product ID:                76487-640-3658033-23932
Original Install Date:     3/16/2012, 2:03:44 PM
System Up Time:            5 Days, 21 Hours, 35 Minutes, 51 Seconds
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              OptiPlex 210L
System type:               X86-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel
~2992 Mhz
```

Comment: Takes a few seconds indeed! And running it again won’t help because it doesn’t cache the information. Also, the Windows updates cause the part about the architecture to quickly scroll off-screen, so unless you have a large enough buffer, you need to pipe it into `more`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code I used:

```
:arch
set p | findstr /i AMD64 > nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto no64
goto eof
:no64
code to execute
:eof
```