# How can I find out which version of Windows 7 I am running? 64-bit or 32-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS version: 32-bit or 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/96092/os-version-32-bit-or-64-bit)

How can I find out which version of Windows 7 I am running? 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/96092/os-version-32-bit-or-64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click Computer->properties. Under system look at "system type", there you have it.