# Will a 64 bit software have a poor performance if it's installed in Program Files (x86)?

Tags: windows

I just noticed some of my softwares and games were installed in the "wrong" folder. Installing them all over again can be a pain. Is that important though?

Comment: See: [Why does 64-bit Windows need a separate “Program Files (x86)” folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/442246/why-does-64-bit-windows-need-a-separate-program-files-x86-folder?rq=1)

Comment: Not one little bit, friendo

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter at all.  Its just a convention, but doesn't change anything when it comes to execution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Installation location does not affect performance. A 64-bit app will always be 64-bit no matter where it's installed.

- The location where the program is installed only affects how the programs are organized. The program binaries are still the same, and a 64-bit application will always be 64-bit. This holds regardless of where the app is installed, whether it's in either Program Files folder or elsewhere on the system.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Or, at least, it shouldn't be.  The separate ones exist so you have a clear visual separation of your 32 and 64 bit apps.  At least, from when we used to care bout such things.