# Clean program re-installation Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation

Currently, my user programs are installed in the standard folders `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`, where I created subfolders for them. (Windows 10, 64 bit)
Now I decided to make one `C:\CustomPrograms` folder (*), where I put all my installs for a better overview. Can I just deinstall the programs and reinstall them in this location, or will that create some data mess/residues (registry etc.)?

(*) For the sake of not having two different locations and for some programs not accepting spaces in file paths.

Plus, is there any need to separate 32-bit programs from 64-bit ones?

Comment: For a reason why it is the way it is: https://superuser.com/questions/442246/why-does-64-bit-windows-need-a-separate-program-files-x86-folder

Comment: The proposed duplicate addresses why there are two directories, but doesn't really answer the question asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can I just deinstall the programs and reinstall them in this location?

Yes.

If, when you install your programs, you are prompted for an install directory then you can install them wherever you like. I have mine installed, where possible, in `c:\apps`

> Will that create some data mess/residues (registry etc.)?

Only if the program uninstall routines are poorly written.

There are specialist uninstall programs, for example [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html), that will clean up leftovers from a standard install if there are any.

---

#### Is there any need to separate 32bit programs from 64bit ones?

No.

There is no need to have separate root install directories for 32-bit and 64-bit programs.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer! Would you also comment on the aspect of  any data clutter upon _re_-installation, so I can tick your answer? E.g.: I want to deinstall a program from `C:/Program Files/MyLocation/ProgramX/` and re-install it to `C:/Apps/ProgramX`.

Comment: @LCsa Answer updated.

Comment: @Revo Uninstaller: Does having changed the default installation directory still make it a "default install"?

Comment: @LCsa I believe so.